# Mantis Bugtracker: File download stops after 4Kb has been downloaded

Tags: php, iis-7, download, mantis, bug-tracker

I'm having an issue with Mantis Bugtracker (version 1.1.8), where file downloads only reach 4 Kb, and then stop. I don't know if this is a problem in the product itself, or in the PHP installation on the server. I've tried disabling output buffering (that was the only value close to 4Kb), but that didn't help.

The files are stored in the database. The application is running on IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 and Sql Server 2005, and the installed version of PHP is 5.2.11.

Does anyone have a solution that might help fix this?

Comment: I'll prepare for backlash ... don't use IIS or SQL Server or Windows for a start :) ... but seriously... is this all users? Specific browsers? Anything is the web server logs?

Comment: What? You think that's a bad setup for running PHP? ;) I know, but the server configuration is out of my hands. It's a problem for all users, in Chrome, IE and Firefox (haven't tried other browsers). I have tried disabling the antivirus/firewall software, that didn't help.

Comment: I would use something like `curl -vvv` to download the file. You would need to log in using a browser and set the cookie manually for curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think that I'm just going to have to face the fact that I'm an idiot. I had changed the textsize and textlimit properties in php.ini for MSSQL, but I missed the semicolon in the beginning of the lines. I just uncommented those two lines, and now it works like a charm.

```
; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
mssql.textlimit = 2147483647 

; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
mssql.textsize = 2147483647
```

Answer (score 0):

OK ... 1st thought would be that it is bizzarly timing out?

You could try setting a max timeout...

Also, knock up an independant bit of code to fetch and download file - to rule out/in any bugs in Mantis ... I use a Mantis but hosted on linux and it all works fine - same vervsion but linux and mysql...

OK A quick serach on mantis's forum gave me: http://www.mantisbt.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4712 which describes exactly what you have happening and it is indeed a specific Windows/ISI/SQL Server thing ;)